# Display picture to the left of a div card

Tags: html, css, image, flexbox, css-float

For a project, I need to reproduce the following [card element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKmGv.png).

However, I have a little problem, I just can't put the picture to the left. I tried to use `float: left;` and some, quite questionable, other means but it just doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```css
#accommodation-popular {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
  border: 1px solid #F2F2F2;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 16px 0px 0px 16px;
}

#popular-nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}

.popular-item {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 10px 5px 5px #E0DDDD;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: max-content;
  max-width: 250px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.popular-picture {
  border: 3px solid white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 180px;
  height: 100px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/                  
             1f544e41e8.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="accommodation-popular">
  <h3>Most popular</h3>
  <i style="color: black;" class="fa-solid fa-star fa-xm"></i>
  <div id="popular-nav">
    <div class="popular-item">
      <img class="popular-picture" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPMiJ.jpg">
      <h5>Morning Sun Hotel</h5>
      <p>Night starting at <strong>128€</strong></p>
      <i style="color: #0065FC;" class="fa-solid fa-star fa-2xs"></i>
      <i style="color: #0065FC;" class="fa-solid fa-star fa-2xs"></i>
      <i style="color: #0065FC;" class="fa-solid fa-star fa-2xs"></i>
      <i style="color: #0065FC;" class="fa-solid fa-star fa-2xs"></i>
      <i style="color: #0065FC;" class="fa-solid fa-star fa-2xs"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="popular-item">
      <img class="popular-picture" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/uW6MA.jpg">
      <h5>Au coeur de l'eau Bed and Breakfast</h5>
      <p>Night starting at <strong>71€</strong></p>
      <i style="color: #0065FC;" class="fa-solid fa-star fa-2xs"></i>
      <i style="color: #0065FC;" class="fa-solid fa-star fa-2xs"></i>
      <i style="color: #0065FC;" class="fa-solid fa-star fa-2xs"></i>
      <i style="color: #0065FC;" class="fa-solid fa-star fa-2xs"></i>
      <i style="color: #dfdddd;" class="fa-solid fa-star fa-2xs"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="popular-item">
      <img class="popular-picture" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptKan.jpg">
      <h5>Tout bleu et Blanc Hotel</h5>
      <p>Night starting at <strong>68€</strong></p>
      <i style="color: #0065FC;" class="fa-solid fa-star fa-2xs"></i>
      <i style="color: #0065FC;" class="fa-solid fa-star fa-2xs"></i>
      <i style="color: #0065FC;" class="fa-solid fa-star fa-2xs"></i>
      <i style="color: #0065FC;" class="fa-solid fa-star fa-2xs"></i>
      <i style="color: #dfdddd;" class="fa-solid fa-star fa-2xs"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I thank in advance anybody who will take the time to try to help me.

Comment: With `width: max-content; max-width: 250px;` on `.popular-item`, there is almost no space for the content to float around the image (The `Au` from the start of your second card headline fits next to that image, everything else doesn't.) Plus, this should rather be done using flexbox in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `flex` as an alternative to `float` makes more sense here. Because you have item info and a picture it makes sense to group the item info in a div so that they are grouped together when you set `display: flex;` on the parent `.popular-item`. I called the grouped item info `.info-container`.

**Pro tip:** You can specify `margin- left, right,` and `bottom` of 10px by writing: `margin: 0px 10px 10px` but I think `padding` is more fitting here since you are trying to create space within the element.

```css
#accommodation-popular {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
  border: 1px solid #F2F2F2;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 16px 0px 0px 16px;
}

#popular-nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  gap: 1em;
}

.popular-item {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 10px 5px 5px #E0DDDD;
  padding: 0 3px 3px;
  max-width: 375px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1em;
}

.popular-picture {
  border: 3px solid white;
  border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
  max-width: 50%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 225px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/1f544e41e8.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="accommodation-popular">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <h3>Most popular</h3>
    <i style="color: black;" class="fa-solid fa-star fa-xm"></i>
  </div>
  <div id="popular-nav">
    <div class="popular-item">
      <img class="popular-picture" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPMiJ.jpg">
      <div class="info-container">
        <h5>Morning Sun Hotel</h5>
        <p>Night starting at <strong>128€</strong></p>
        <i style="color: #0065FC;" class="fa-solid fa-star fa-2xs"></i>
        <i style="color: #0065FC;" class="fa-solid fa-star fa-2xs"></i>
        <i style="color: #0065FC;" class="fa-solid fa-star fa-2xs"></i>
        <i style="color: #0065FC;" class="fa-solid fa-star fa-2xs"></i>
        <i style="color: #0065FC;" class="fa-solid fa-star fa-2xs"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="popular-item">
      <img class="popular-picture" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/uW6MA.jpg">
      <div class="info-container">
        <h5>Au coeur de l'eau Bed and Breakfast</h5>
        <p>Night starting at <strong>71€</strong></p>
        <i style="color: #0065FC;" class="fa-solid fa-star fa-2xs"></i>
        <i style="color: #0065FC;" class="fa-solid fa-star fa-2xs"></i>
        <i style="color: #0065FC;" class="fa-solid fa-star fa-2xs"></i>
        <i style="color: #0065FC;" class="fa-solid fa-star fa-2xs"></i>
        <i style="color: #0065FC;" class="fa-solid fa-star fa-2xs"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="popular-item">
      <img class="popular-picture" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptKan.jpg">
      <div class="info-container">
        <h5>Tout bleu et Blanc Hotel</h5>
        <p>Night starting at <strong>68€</strong></p>
        <i style="color: #0065FC;" class="fa-solid fa-star fa-2xs"></i>
        <i style="color: #0065FC;" class="fa-solid fa-star fa-2xs"></i>
        <i style="color: #0065FC;" class="fa-solid fa-star fa-2xs"></i>
        <i style="color: #0065FC;" class="fa-solid fa-star fa-2xs"></i>
        <i style="color: #0065FC;" class="fa-solid fa-star fa-2xs"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a CSS solution to your issue, but usually an easiest way to solve this kind of issue is to use a table. You can put your image on the left column, and your text on the right.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the "max-width" of the container to be 250px.

Change it to a static width instead and also fix the positioning of the texts ->

```css
#accommodation-popular {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
  border: 1px solid #F2F2F2;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 16px 0px 0px 16px;
}

#popular-nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}

.popular-item {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 10px 5px 5px #E0DDDD;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: max-content;
  width: 300px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.popular-picture {
  border: 3px solid white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 15px 0px 0px 15px;
}

.popular-content {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="accommodation-popular">
  <h3>Most popular</h3>
  <i style="color: black;" class="fa-solid fa-star fa-xm"></i>
  <div id="popular-nav">
    <div class="popular-item">
      <img class="popular-picture" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPMiJ.jpg">
      <div class='popular-content'><h5>Morning Sun Hotel</h5>
      <p>Night starting at <strong>128€</strong></p>
      <i style="color: #0065FC;" class="fa-solid fa-star fa-2xs"></i>
      <i style="color: #0065FC;" class="fa-solid fa-star fa-2xs"></i>
      <i style="color: #0065FC;" class="fa-solid fa-star fa-2xs"></i>
      <i style="color: #0065FC;" class="fa-solid fa-star fa-2xs"></i>
      <i style="color: #0065FC;" class="fa-solid fa-star fa-2xs"></i>
      </div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add display: flex to popular-item. And also increase the max-width to fit your content.

```
.popular-item {
  display: flex;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 10px 5px 5px #E0DDDD;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: max-content;
  max-width: 250px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```